# How to make 'send' non-blocking in winsock

Tags: c++, windows, winsock

I am making a program which sends UDP packets to a server at a fixed interval, something like this:

```
while (!stop) {
    Sleep(fixedInterval);

    send(sock, pkt, payloadSize, flags);
 }
```

However the periodicity cannot be guaranteed because `send` is a blocking call (e.g., when `fixedInterval` is 20ms, and a call to `send` is > 20ms ). Do you know how I can turn the `send` into a non-blocking operation?

Comment: Like describe [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API ioctlsocket can do it.You can use it as below.But why don't you use I/O models in winsock?

`ioctlsocket(hsock,FIOBIO,(unsigned long *)&ul);`

Comment: Thanks, which winsock I/O mode should I use?

Comment: @ZhiWang: Non-blocking, obviously.

Comment: You mean FIONBIO instead of FIOBIO ?

Comment: i add a check that 'ioctlsocket' completed correctly:                                                                                    if (ioctlsocket(m_bind_socket, FIONBIO, &nonblocking) == SOCKET_ERROR

Answer (score 15):

You need to use a non-blocking socket.  The send/receive functions are the same functions for blocking or non-blocking operations, but you must set the socket itself to non-blocking.

```
u_long mode = 1;  // 1 to enable non-blocking socket
ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &mode);
```

Also, be aware that working with non-blocking sockets is quite different.  You'll need to make sure you handle WSAEWOULDBLOCK errors as success!  :)

So, using non-blocking sockets may help, but still will not guarantee an exact period.  You would be better to drive this from a timer, rather than this simple loop, so that any latency from calling send, even in non-blocking mode, will not affect the timing.

Comment: `fcntl()` and `O_NONBLOCK` do not exist on Windows. The Windows equivilent of `O_NONBLOCK` is to enable `FIONBIO` with `ioctlsocket()`.

Comment: Yes, your are right of course.  I have edited my answer to use the correct windows function.

Answer (score 0):

My memory is fuzzy here since it's probably been 15 years since I've used UDP non-blocking.

However, there are some things of which you should be aware.

1. Send only smallish packets if you're going over a public network.  The PATH MTU can trip you up if either the client or the server is not written to take care of incomplete packets.
2. Make sure you check that you have sent the number of bytes you think you have to send.  It can get weird when you're expecting to see 300 bytes sent and the receiving end only gets 248. Both client side and server side have to be aware of this issue.
3. See [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html) for some good advice from the Linux folks.
4. See [here](http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=3018) for the Unix Socket FAQ for UDP
5. [This](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html) is a good, general network programming FAQ and example page.

Comment: UDP won't send partial packets.

Comment: Also you won't _receive_ partial datagrams, it is all or nothing, nor will the MTU be an issue for any _reasonable_ packet size (not necessary to stay particularly small). Both IPv4 and IPv6 support fragmentation, which works just fine (apart from some the obvious in presence of packet loss).

Comment: @EJP: I have seen (and had to fix) a problem with partial UDP packets many moons ago.  The problem was the PMTU and sent, fixed size packets that were bigger than the buffers in the OS.  The magic number was around 8K bytes. I don't remember if said OS was Netware, WinNt 3.x or OS/2, but I remember having to fix it.

Comment: @Damon: Is 8K a reasonable packet size?  Around that size was not when the Windows ping of death was fashionable.

Comment: @JimR: 8kiB is quite big and probably not ideal, but it's certainly allowable. On present-day internet (IPv6-capable routers) this will generate 7 fragments. Of course this makes you somewhat more susceptible to packet loss (as 1 fragment lost = whole packet lost), but you should still be good in most situations. If a router starts dropping, it usually drops in dozens anyway, and packet loss due to "line noise" is extremely rare. Whether Windows was not able to handle legitimate packets once upon a time is irrelevant. You can't consider every historic broken implementation.

Comment: @JimR: I wouldn't try to approach the 64k limit with UDP packet sizes (though even that _should_ work), but for anything ranging from, say 1k to 10k, I wouldn't really worry. It's all the same.  Ideally, of course, you'd stay below 1280 if you can help it easily (as to avoid fragmentation). But if you can't help it, so what. One should consider that if one has dozens to hundreds (thousands, millions) of kilobytes to send, one would probably want to use TCP anyway. Size eventually becomes "unreasonable" as your usage is contrary to what the protocol was intended for.

Comment: @JimR: You use UDP if you want minimum latency, and don't need the delivery and order guarantees given by TCP. This more or less automatically presumes a short message lifetime, too. If you can't live with ignoring a packet that is lost, and ignoring it _quickly_ (because it won't matter after some milliseconds) then you really do not want to use UDP. Which, at the same time, means that sending messages of several tens of kiB in size is probably not very sensible, even though it works.

Comment: @Damon: I agree with most of your statements.  If you look at my original answer, I said "Things to be aware of" -- not "Don't do this or your software won't work".  Sticking with smallish packets and being able to tell if they're complete, unaltered packets is a good thing.

Comment: @Damon: Also, the Windows ping of death statement was meant to set a timeframe...  I remember fixing said packet problem when the ping of death was in the news.  It also happens that at that time I was working on 4 or more different OS platforms.

Answer (score 0):

How about measuring the time Send takes and then just sleeping the time missing up to the 20ms?

Comment: What if the send takes longer than the sleep time?

Comment: @EJP: Then the timing would be as off as with non-blocking sends.