# How to receive multiple files through TCP and save them at the same time in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, winsock2

I'm trying to create an app which would accept many connections from clients at the same time and it works for me, but it also should download those files at the same time. In this version of server, even if clients are connected simultaneously, files are written one by one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int winsock_result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

    if(winsock_result != 0)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKET server_socket;
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if(server_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    int const max_clients = 100;
    int client_socket[max_clients];

    for (int i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
    {
        client_socket[i] = 0;
    }

    char* ip_address = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 6666;

    SOCKADDR_IN server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_address);
    int server_sizeof = sizeof(server);

    int opt = TRUE;
    if( setsockopt(server_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0 )
    {
        closesocket(server_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }


    if(bind(server_socket,(SOCKADDR *)&server, server_sizeof) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket(server_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    if(listen(server_socket, 5) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Nasluchiwanie portu nieudane." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Nasluchiwanie portu " << port << " udane." << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    int const buffer_size = 512;
    char buffer[buffer_size];

    int max_socket_descriptor, socket_descriptor;
    int downloaded_files = 1;

    fd_set readfds;

    while(true)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(server_socket, &readfds);
        max_socket_descriptor = server_socket;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++)
        {
            socket_descriptor = client_socket[i];
            if(socket_descriptor > 0)
            {
                FD_SET( socket_descriptor, &readfds);
            }

            if(socket_descriptor > max_socket_descriptor)
            {
                max_socket_descriptor = socket_descriptor;
            }
        }

        if ((select( max_socket_descriptor + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0) && (errno != EINTR))
        {
            std::cout << "Blad funkcji select." << std::endl;
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(server_socket, &readfds))
        {
            int new_sockfd;
            if ((new_sockfd = accept(server_socket,(SOCKADDR *)&server, &server_sizeof)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                std::cout << "Otrzymanie deskryptora nieudane." << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
                {
                    if( client_socket[i] == 0 )
                    {
                        client_socket[i] = new_sockfd;
                        std::cout << "Dodawanie do listy socketow jako numer " << i << std::endl;

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
        {
            socket_descriptor = client_socket[i];

            if (FD_ISSET( socket_descriptor, &readfds))
            {
                struct sockaddr_in client_address;

                char filename[buffer_size];
                std::stringstream ip_filename;
                ip_filename << "plik" << downloaded_files << "_" << inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr);
                strcpy(filename, ip_filename.str().c_str());

                std::cout << "Nazwa pliku (IP klienta): " << filename << std::endl;

                FILE* file;
                file = fopen(filename, "wb");

                const clock_t begin_time = clock();
                int received_size;

                do
                {
                    memset(buffer, 0, buffer_size);
                    received_size = recv(socket_descriptor, buffer, buffer_size, 0);

                    if (received_size == 0 || received_size == -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), received_size, file);
                }
                while (received_size != 0);

                fclose(file);
                std::cout << "Czas wysylania pliku: " << float( clock () - begin_time ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " sekund." << std::endl << std::endl;

                closesocket(socket_descriptor);
                client_socket[i] = 0;

                downloaded_files++;
            }
        }
    }

    closesocket(server_socket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

What should I do to make them write many at the same time? I've tried many modifications of the code above but every time I can't get wanted result.
For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int winsock_result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

    if(winsock_result != 0)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKET server_socket;
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if(server_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    int const max_clients = 100;
    int client_socket[max_clients];

    for (int i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
    {
        client_socket[i] = 0;
    }

    char* ip_address = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 6666;

    SOCKADDR_IN server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_address);
    int server_sizeof = sizeof(server);

    int opt = TRUE;
    if( setsockopt(server_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0 )
    {
        closesocket(server_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }


    if(bind(server_socket,(SOCKADDR *)&server, server_sizeof) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket(server_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    if(listen(server_socket, 5) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Nasluchiwanie portu nieudane." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Nasluchiwanie portu " << port << " udane." << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    int const buffer_size = 512;
    char buffer[buffer_size];

    int max_socket_descriptor;
    int downloaded_files = 1;

    fd_set readfds;
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(server_socket, &readfds);
    max_socket_descriptor = server_socket;

    while(true)
    {
        if ((select( max_socket_descriptor + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0) && (errno != EINTR))
        {
            std::cout << "Blad funkcji select." << std::endl;
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++)
        {
            if(FD_ISSET(server_socket, &readfds))
            {
                int new_sockfd;
                if ((new_sockfd = accept(server_socket,(SOCKADDR *)&server, &server_sizeof)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    std::cout << "Otrzymanie deskryptora nieudane." << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
                    {
                        if( client_socket[i] == 0 )
                        {
                            client_socket[i] = new_sockfd;
                            FD_SET( client_socket[i], &readfds);

                            if(client_socket[i] > max_socket_descriptor)
                            {
                                max_socket_descriptor = client_socket[i];
                            }

                            std::cout << "Dodawanie do listy socketow jako numer " << i << std::endl;

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(FD_ISSET(client_socket[i], &readfds))
            {
                struct sockaddr_in client_address;

                char filename[buffer_size];
                std::stringstream ip_filename;
                ip_filename << "plik" << downloaded_files << "_" << inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr);
                strcpy(filename, ip_filename.str().c_str());

                std::cout << "Nazwa pliku (IP klienta): " << filename << std::endl;

                FILE* file;

                memset(buffer, 0, buffer_size);
                int received_size;

                received_size = recv(client_socket[i], buffer, buffer_size, 0);

                if (received_size <= 0)
                {
                    closesocket(client_socket[i]);
                    FD_CLR(client_socket[i], &readfds);
                    client_socket[i] = 0;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    file = fopen(filename, "ab");
                    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), received_size, file);
                    fclose(file);
                }

                downloaded_files++;
            }

        }
    }

    closesocket(server_socket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

I thought about opening and closing those files every received packet and appending every packet to them, but I really don't have idea how to do it. The example of modified code was meant to do it, but it doesn't work.

I'm forbidden to use other processes and threads than the main one, so I'm kinda helpless now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use individual processes per client or individual threads per client or write a state machine that processes small chunks of data from each client at a time (in a non-blocking manner) and cycles through clients.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention it. In this task I'm forbidden to use other processes and threads than the main one.

Comment: I thought about opening and closing those files every received packet and appending every packet to them, but I really don't have idea how to do it. The example of modified code was meant to do it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If this is a school assignment, it's a non sense one. When doing Internet related stuff you have to make use of threads anyway.

Comment: Yes, this is a school assignment. I have to do it that way, I have no choice unfortunately.

Comment: Please explain more clearly exactly what you mean by `"it doesn't work"`.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis single threaded servers serving multiple clients were written long before threads (or multi-core processors) were a thing, as were multi-process ones. There's absolutely nothing that *requires* threads in order to serve multiple clients efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the basic loop with `select` in place, which is good.

`accept` is already (mostly) non-blocking. You just need to turn on [non-blocking mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227092/how-to-make-send-non-blocking-in-winsock) on the client sockets and then you'll be able to handle multiple client reads, writes and accepts in your main `select` loop.

You can have a `vector` of client-specific data per client, with each entry containing the client socket, the opened file and any other client-specific state.

After the `accept`, you create a new client entry and add it to the vector. Then in the main loop you do `FD_SET` for `accept` and all client's reads and writes. After the `select`, you inspect the the FD sets and handle them one by one. For best performance you will want your file I/O also in non-blocking mode, but for this assignment that's probably overkill.